# Statistical Estimation Book Request

Tags: statistics, reference-request, parameter-estimation

I am seeking a clear book for parameter estimation, estimation methods, properties of estimators, minimum variance estimators, asymptotic properties of estimators and interval estimation reducution.

Comment: introduction to probability and statistics by Rohatgi and Saleh will help you

Comment: Statistical Inference (Berger and Casella) http://math.nenu.edu.cn/uploads/soft/120716/Casella_Berger_Statistical_Inference.pdf might interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These books address some of these topics and are clear:

Papoulis: Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes

Van Trees: Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory (Part I)

Tarantola: Inverse Problem Theory

Scharf: Statistical Signal Processing

Luenberger: Optimization by Vector State Methods (chapter 4)

Vogel: Computational Methods for Inverse Problems

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into them!

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Mathematical Statistics with Applications" by Dennis D.Wackerly, Mendenhall, Scheaffer.  It has couple of chapters on Estimation & properties of Estimator which are quite readable and easy to understand.